# AWS simple email service hangs at sendRawEmail

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I wrote below nodejs function to send email using AWS SES.
the same code successfully sent emails few times but after that code hangs at `ses.sendRawEmail` i tried increasing timeout and memory allocation but still gives me Task timed out after 60.01 seconds

```
function sendMail( statusJSON){

    var aws     = require('aws-sdk');

// Edit this with YOUR email address.
var fromEmail   = "xxxxxx";
var toEmail   = "xxxxxx";   

// Instantiate SES.
var ses = new aws.SES();
var ses_mail = "From: 'Service Monitor' <" + fromEmail + ">\n";
ses_mail = ses_mail + "To: " + toEmail + "\n";
ses_mail = ses_mail + "Subject: service status: RED\n";
ses_mail = ses_mail + "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n";
ses_mail = ses_mail + "--NextPart\n";
ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\n\n";
ses_mail = ses_mail + JSON.stringify(statusJSON) +".\n\n";
ses_mail = ses_mail + "--NextPart\n";
ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: text/plain;\n";
ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"statusJSON.txt\"\n\n";
ses_mail = ses_mail + JSON.stringify(statusJSON) + "\n\n";
ses_mail = ses_mail + "--NextPart--";

var params = {
    RawMessage: { Data: new Buffer(ses_mail) },
    Destinations: [ toEmail ],
    Source: "'Herald Service Monitor' <" + fromEmail + ">'"
};
ses.sendRawEmail(params, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } 
    else {
        console.log(data);
    }           
});
```

please share your thoughts

Comment: Are you in the Amazon SES sandbox? If so, you might be exceeding your sending quota (200 messages per 24-hour period) or your maximum sending rate (one message per second). If not, you might want to consider [increasing your Amazon SES sending limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/increase-sending-limits.html).

Comment: If this is a Lambda function, this would most likely be caused by the function container not having Internet access.  Over quota should result in a different error.

Comment: That's what I thought at first but then OP says emails are being sent before the function starts to time out after a while. So, I ruled out VPC-related issues.

Comment: Its very wierd behaviour i had arround 191 remaining messages out of the quota of 200 but it wasn't  worki g tried after an hour emails started working.

Comment: happening again email sending is inconsistent 2/10 time method times out

Comment: anyone has answer to it? I'm facing the same problem